# Unable to compile class for JSP while running a struts project

Tags: jsp, struts2, ejb-3.0

i'm working in 3 projects, to implements the injection of EJB in Struts , so i'v no problem with the injection but i get this error whenever i try to run the EAR projct that containts the EJB and struts projects  ,

The problem goew when the server try to show the page JSP , the code of this page is :

```
        <%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
        <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

          <html>
          <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <title>The current date</title>
        </head>
         <body>
             <h1>The current date is: <s:property value="currentDate"/></h1>
                  </body>
           </html>
```

the error is :

JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP: JBWEB004061: An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files JBWEB004211: Stacktrace:

i'm using as server Widlfy 8.0  , JDK 8 
i'v seen other issues with the same problem , but with no result , so thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved , the main problem was the fact that i'm using widlfy 8.0.0 , so as solution for those who are fascing the same problem , either you use 
  -> widlfy 8.0.1
or work with 8.0.0 but do these changes in that link : http://www.tipstrickz.com/fix-jsp-compilation-error-in-wildfly-8-using-java-8/

by default widlfy 8.0.0 cant run jsp files !